# Duplicate an ObservableCollection Item

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I want to duplicate a list item in an observablecollection. When I do:

```
            TreasureCards[TreasureCards.Count - 1] = TreasureCards[CardPosition];
```

It creates a copy of the specific list item but then they are linked in my UI. So if I change the new duplicated item's name, it changes the originals name. I know I could do each of the properties one by one (see below) but is there a way to just copy the entire item?

```
    TreasureCards[TreasureCards.Count - 1].Name = TreasurecCards[CardPosition].Name;
    TreasureCards[TreasureCards.Count - 1].Type= TreasurecCards[CardPosition].Type;

// etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't duplicating the object.  You're creating a new reference to the object.  There's still only one object; now there are two references to it in your collection, and any change to the object is reflected by both references.

To create a new object, you can call `MemberwiseClone()` on anything that derives from `Object`.  This method returns a new instance, copying the values from all fields in the original object.  So you'd do:

```
TreasureCards[TreasureCards.Count - 1] = TreasureCards[CardPosition].MemberwiseClone();
```

There are two limitations with this method.  First, it's a shallow copy, i.e. any reference fields in the original object have their values copied.  So if `a.Foo` is a reference to a `Bar` object, `a.MemberwiseClone().Foo` will refer to the same `Bar` object.  Second, the method just copies the fields; it doesn't call the new object's constructor.  Depending on the design of the class, this is either unimportant or a Really Big Deal.

Usually, it's safer to make the class implement `ICloneable` and explicitly implement a `Clone()` method, e.g.:

```
public TreasureCard Clone()
{
   return new TreasureCard
   {
      Name = this.Name,
      Type = this.Type,
      ...
   };
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my delay in response I haven't had a chance to work on my project until now. Thank you for your help Robert - I was able to get my clone to work!

Answer (score 1):

They aren't linked, they are the same instance.  All you're doing is copying a reference to the same data to another position in the array.

What you need to do is implement some Clone method that makes a copy of the original instance but as another instance.  This SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c) might help.

Then you would do something like this:

```
 TreasureCards[TreasureCards.Count - 1] = TreasureCards[CardPosition].Clone();
```